# synchronize property getters/setters

Tags: java, kotlin

So I'm trying to get a handle on how Kotlin handles synchronization of properties. If I have this class:

```
class Foo {
    var a = 0
    var b = 0
}
```

and I want to make sure that a & b have all access synchronized. How would I do it? I've tried using the annotation:

```
class Foo {
    @Synchronized
    var a = 0
    @Synchronized
    var b = 0
}
```

but Kotlin gives me a compiler error:

> This annotation is not applicable to target 'member property with backing field'

I'm just trying to get a better handle on thread safety in Kotlin. It's something that I've always been OCD about in Java, and I'm trying to figure out how to properly handle it in Kotlin.

Answer (score 43):

You can't synchronize on a property but you can synchronize on the accessor methods. Use the following syntax:

```
class Foo {
    var a = 0
        @Synchronized get
        @Synchronized set   

    //or

    @get:Synchronized @set:Synchronized
    var b = 0
}
```

Comment: has this syntax always been in Kotlin? if not, what version was it introduced?

Comment: I think it was always there.

Comment: Does this lock on `Foo` or on the created setter and getter functions?

Comment: @stk instance functions aren't objects so you can't lock on them. Therefore it must lock on the `Foo` instance.

Answer (score 6):

Followed by the @Kirill Rakhman's answer, use of **Delegates** could be more performant if there is tons of contention to the same object since it locks on the delegate rather than the whole object.

```
class Foo {
    var a by Synchronize(0)
    var b by Synchronize(0)
}

class Synchronize<T>(defaultValue: T): ReadWriteProperty<Any, T> {
    private var backingField = defaultValue

    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return synchronized(this) {
            backingField
        }
    }

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        synchronized(this) {
            backingField = value
        }
    }
}
```

References: 
[Kotlin Delegated Properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#property-delegate-requirements)
[Reddit Discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/6r01v5/kotlin_and_property_thread_safety/)

Comment: Why this is not part of sdk ? It looks quite useful ... Any issues with this approach ?

Comment: I am using this and no issue till now. Maybe it will be added later. Hope so.